# Multiple rewrite rules in nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

so I'm trying to use multiple rewrite rules in nginx, however what I'm trying isn't working.

```
    location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.png break;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.jpg break;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.gif break;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.txt break;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.rar break;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.zip break;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.mp3 break;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.mp4 break;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

This is my config, but the first rule, the png one, is the only one that works, the rest return a 404.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The `rewrite` directive does not check if the rewritten URI exists, so

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.png break;
```

just adds `.png` to each URL that does not resolve to a file and stops rewriting (`break`).

What you are looking for is the `try_files` directive, that you already have. You probably want something like:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.png $uri.jpg $uri.gif ...
```

I am unsure, what you want to achieve with `/index.php?query_string`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, it seems that it downloads the images using try_files.

Comment: Suppose a user asks for `/search?q=aaaa`. If no image file of the form `search.<your_extensions>` exist, **nginx** will try `/index.php?q=aaaa`, which hardly is what you want, but I don't know what `index.php` is.